# Do the values of the global dimension constitute an interval?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $Q$ be a fixed finite connected quiver and $k$ a fixed field. Set $Z_Q:= \{ gldim(kQ/I) < \infty | I $ an admissible ideal $\}$.

> Question: Is $Z_Q$ an intervall?

This is true for example in case $Q$ has $n$ points and is a linear oriented line (here $Z_Q=\{1,2,...,n-1 \})$ or a linear oriented cycle (here $Z_Q=\{2,3,...,2n-2 \}$).

Comment: Possibly relevant, although I don't immediately see how to relate the two problems: the set of global dimensions of generating-cogenerating $kQ$-modules is an interval, at least when $Q$ is acyclic, by a result of Dlab–Ringel (https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~ringel/opus/dr.pdf). (I think this problem is open for arbitrary finite-dimensional algebras, up to the small caveat that in general one should restrict to the set of finite global dimensions, which is not necessary for the positive result in the hereditary case.)